# Given cos(t)=$(1/2)$($e^{it}$+$e^{-it}$), solve for $\cos^{-1}$(x)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given $\cos(t)=\frac12(e^{it}+e^{-it}$), solve for $\cos^{-1}$(x) in terms of logs/roots. The hint says to let $x=\cos(t)$ and $z=e^{it}$. So I started first by substituting:

$x=\frac12(z+1/z)$  --> multiply both sides by 2z

$2xz=z^2+1$

$z^2 -2zx +1 = 0$  --> quadratic formula, solve for z

$z =x ± \sqrt{x^2-1}$

I'm supposed to solve for t now, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done the hard part. Choosing the positive square root, you have $it = \log(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$ (where $\log = \ln$). It's easy enough to solve for $t$ by multiplying by $-i$.

Note that $x-\sqrt{x^2-1} = \dfrac 1{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, so, indeed, $-it = -\log(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}) = \log(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$.

Comment: gotcha. makes sense!