# Solving $\cos(2z) + (2-2i)\cos(z) = 2i-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve $$\cos(2z) + (2-2i)\cos(z) = 2i-1$$ when $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

**My work so far**

I want to use formula $\cos(2z) = 2\cos^2(z) - 1$ to expand $\cos(2z)$:

$$2\cos^2(z) - 1 + (2-2i)\cos(z) = 2i-1$$
Let $t := \cos(z)$

$$2t^2 - 1 +2t - 2it -2i + 1 =0$$
$$2t^2 + 2t(1-i) - 2i =0$$
$$t^2 + t(1-i) - i = 0$$
$$\Delta = (1-i)^2 - 4 \cdot (-i) = (1-i)^2 + 4i = 1-2i-1+4i = 2i$$
$$\sqrt{\Delta} = \sqrt{2i}$$

So it turns out that $t = \frac{1 - i \pm \sqrt{2i}}{2}$

Expanding $t$ as $cos(z)$ and using fact that $cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$ we end up with:

$$e^{iz} + e^{-iz} = 1-i\pm\sqrt{2i}$$

and here I got stuck, I'm not sure what should I do next. I tried to multiply by $e^{ix}$ but it doesn't seem to be a good idea. I tried to use fact that $\sqrt{i} = \cos(\pi / 4) + i \sin(\pi /4)$ but it also brought me nothing. Could you please help me solving this equation?

Comment: Multiply with $e^{iz}$ and solve a quadratic equation ...

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3016376/42969

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong here since

$$t^2 + t(1-i) - i = 0 \iff t=-1 \quad \lor \quad  t=i$$

and then we almost done indeed

- $\cos z=-1 \iff z=\pi + 2n\pi$
- $\cos z=i \iff e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2i \iff e^{2iz}-2ie^{iz}+1=0$

which is a quadratic in $e^{iz}$.